# RedisTemplate with Lettuce seems to get new connection on each request

Tags: spring-data-redis

For a spring boot app I am using RedisTemplate injected into a service bean to do simple gets/sets. This is for AWS Elasticache cluster enabled. I started the app and sent a few requests thru and the performance is slow and the Elasticache metrics show new connections equivalent to the number of requests.  By slow I am seeing times of roughly 100ms for each call.  The long latency and metrics for new connections indicates the native connection in the LettuceConnection is not retained.  I am only using spring-data to manage getting the connection setup.  Specifically, I don't want to connect in a @Config class and have the app fail on startup if there is an issue connecting. It's a critical app that needs to start even if the cache is not available at that time.  And I don't want to write the code to synchronize getting the single native connection during multi-threaded access.  Any ideas why the native connection would not be saved?  Here's my config:

```
    private ClusterClientOptions clusterClientOptions() {
    //@formatter:off
    return ClusterClientOptions.builder()
            .socketOptions(SocketOptions
                    .builder()
                    .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(properties.getConnectionTimeoutMs()))
                    .build())
            .requestQueueSize(properties.getRequestQueueSize())
            .topologyRefreshOptions(ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions
                    .builder()
                    .enablePeriodicRefresh(properties.isPeriodicRefresh())
                    .build())
            .build();
    //@formatter:on
}

private LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceClientConfiguration() {
    //@formatter:off
    return LettuceClientConfiguration
        .builder()
        .clientOptions(clusterClientOptions())
        .commandTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(properties.getCommandTimeoutMs()))
        .useSsl()
        .build();
    //@formatter:on
}

private LettuceConnectionFactory serviceContextLettuceConnectionFactory() {

    RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfig = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
    clusterConfig.clusterNode(properties.getCacheEndpoint(), properties.getCachePort());
    clusterConfig.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(properties.getCachePassword()));

    LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory =
            new LettuceConnectionFactory(clusterConfig, lettuceClientConfiguration());
    lettuceConnectionFactory.setShareNativeConnection(true);
    lettuceConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return lettuceConnectionFactory;
}

private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, String> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(serviceContextLettuceConnectionFactory());
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template;
}
```

The template gets set into a singleton service class which calls template.opsForValue().get(key), etc.  It works but it's slow and always creating new connections.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: there was @RefreshScope in this @Configuration class (not shown) which caused a different behavior than I expected.  Still not 100% sure of the details but it seemed to be recreating the factory and template each time causing the new connections.  I removed that annotation and it is re-using the native connection as expected